# Why Principle Components of Covariance matrix capture maximum variance of the variables?

Tags: statistics, linear-algebra, pca, eigenvector

I am trying to understand PCA, I went through several tutorials. So far I understand that, the eigenvectors of a matrix implies the directions in which vectors are rotated and scaled when multiplied by that matrix, in proportion of the eigenvalues. Hence the eigenvector associated with the maximum Eigen value defines direction of maximum rotation. I understand that along the principle component, the variations are maximum and reconstruction errors are minimum. What I do not understand is:

**why finding the Eigen vectors of the *covariance matrix* corresponds to the axis such that the original variables are better defined with this axis?**

In addition to tutorials, I reviewed other answers here including [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217995/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-how-pca-turns-from-a-geometric-problem-wit). But still I do not understand it.

Comment: which part is causing trouble? You don't necessarily need "rotation" concept for this.

Comment: @percusse, right. to rephrase, why  the Eigen vectors of the covariance matrix corresponds to the axis such that the original variables are better defined with this axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect. PCA (and eigenvectors of a covariance matrix) certainly don't represent the original data "better".

Briefly, the goal of PCA is to find some lower dimensional representation of your data (`X`, which is in `n` dimensions) such that as much of the variation is retained as possible. The upshot is that this lower dimensional representation is an orthogonal subspace and it's the *best* `k` dimensional representation (where `k < n`) of your data. We must find that subspace.

Another way to think about this: given a data matrix `X` find a matrix `Y` such that `Y` is a `k`-dimensional projection of `X`. To find the *best* projection, we can just minimize the difference between `X` and `Y`, which in matrix-speak means minimizing `||X - Y||^2`.

Since `Y` is just a projection of `X` onto lower dimensions, we can say `Y = X*v` where `v*v^T` is a lower rank projection. Google `rank` if this doesn't make sense. We know `Xv` is a lower dimension than `X`, but we don't know what direction it points.

To do that, we find the `v` such that `||X - X*v*v^t||^2` is minimized. This is equivalent to maximizing `||X*v||^2 = ||v^T*X^T*X*v||` and `X^T*X` is the sample covariance matrix of your data. This is mathematically why we care about the covariance of the data. Also, it turns out that the `v` that does this the best, is an eigenvector. There is one eigenvector for each dimension in the lower dimensional projection/approximation. These eigenvectors are also orthogonal.

Remember, if they are orthogonal, then the covariance between any two of them is `0`. Now think of a matrix with non-zero diagonals and zero's in the off-diagonals. This is a covariance matrix of orthogonal columns, i.e. each column is an eigenvector.

Hopefully that helps bridge the connection between covariance matrix and how it helps to yield the best lower dimensional subspace.

Again, eigenvectors don't better define our original variables. The axis determined by applying PCA to a dataset are linear combinations of our original variables that tend to exhibit maximum variance and produce the closest possible approximation to our original data (as measured by l2 norm).

Comment: thanks. Can you please elaborate on 'if they are orthogonal, then the covariance between any two of them is '. For the original data (lets say 2D), the x and y axes are orthogonal, but covariance can be nonzero. then why they have to be zero in case of using the eigenvectors as new axes?

Comment: The covariance between two orthogonal variables (or dimensions, axis, features, ...) is 0. That should be obvious by the definition/formula of covariance. X and Y axis are indeed orthogonal, but the original variables don't lie exactly on X or Y axis right? They are likely to have a non-zero X value and a non-zero Y value. PCA tries to find orthogonal axis on which to project these data points.

Comment: @Rakib lol I was stuck on that same question for a long time, and then I realized its not at all that complicated. It's not just that the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix *(the new features that we'll be projecting onto)* are orthogonal that makes the covariance zero. It's the fact that the eigenvectors are orthogonal AFTER one of them has been transformed by the covariance matrix that makes the covariances zero! Here, I'll explain. For our original features, say we're using the X and Y axes, so the "units" of the features along those directions would be i and j (basis vectors).

Comment: To get the covariance between the two, we would compute (i^T)C(j), where C is the covariance matrix of the original dataset. As you can see, even though the X and Y axes are orthogonal, meaning that (i^T)(j)=0, (i^T)C(j) is NOT 0, and instead gives me the element in the second column first row of the covariance matrix *(the covariance between the feature on the X axis and the feature on the Y axis, what we were looking for.)* However, if we instead pick features (u1) and (u2) that ARE eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, then (u1^T)C(u2)=0, AND (u1)^T(u2)=0.

Comment: FInding new features has three requirements: the variance of the first one must be maximum, the covariances of any two must be zero, and they must be orthogonal to one another. Choosing them to be the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix satisfies all three. However, don't confuse the features being orthogonal for them having zero covariance with one another. Orthogonality is satisfied by (u1)^T(u2)=0, while zero covariance is satisfied by (u1)^T(C)(u2)=0